$f$ convex $\Rightarrow$ $L(f)\geq f$
Assume that $L:C[a,b]\to C[a,b]$ is a sequence of linear operator acting on the set $C[a,b]$ of continuous functions over [a,b]. Besides, $L(1)=1$ and $L(x)=x$. I recently found that from this is trivial that $L(f)\geq f$ in $[a,b]$. But I cant see it. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

I am confused. Can you clarify what you mean by this? $L_n(f) \geq f$ absolutely need not be true if $L_n$ is just a linear operator sending $1$ to $1$ and $x$ to $x$.

$L_n(f)$ is just another function. I would like to see how $L_n(f)(x)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

Does the subscript $n$ mean something?

Not for the question indeed. I edit it.

I do not see any sequence. I see just one operator, $L$.

Is $L$ order-preserving, so that $f \le g \implies L(f) \le L(g)$?

In this case, yes. But is it possible to have $L(f)\geq f$ without assuming the order-preserving?

That is not true in general. For a counterexample, let
$$
 L(f)(x) = f(x) - f(a) + 2 f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) - f(b)  \, .
$$
Then $L(1) = 1$ and $L(x) = x$, but $L(f) < f$ for any strictly convex function $f$. Concretely:
$$
 L(x^2) = x^2 - \frac{(b-a)^2}{2} < x^2 \, .
$$

The statement becomes true if $L$ is order-preserving, i.e. if $L(g) \le L(h)$ for $g \le h $.
Proof: Fix $x_0 \in (a, b)$ and let $c \in \Bbb R$ be a subderivative of $f$ at $x_0$, so that
$$
  \forall x \in [a, b]: f(x) \ge f(x_0) + c (x-x_0) =: l(x) \, .
$$
(Such a subderivative exists because $f$ is convex.) Then
$$ 
 f \ge l \implies L(f) \ge L(l) = l
$$
and in particular
$$ 
   L(f)(x_0) \ge l(x_0) = f(x_0) \, .
$$
Since $f$ is continuous this holds for $x_0 = a, b$ as well, so that $L(f) \ge f$.
